# Who sent the group to the Game Preserve Planet in Predators

Tags: predator-series, predators-2010

Any idea who sent the gang of extremely dangerous individuals to the unknown planet (or moon, since you see a huge Jupiter like planet nearby) in Predators that Royce described as the *Game Preserve Planet*.
Is it the Weyland company or any other entity, was that referenced in some tie-in materials?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Predators drop the group on the moon

---

This is addressed in the movie where Noland tells the others about it:

> NOLAND: Far as I can tell, a game preserve. And you and I are the game.
>
> ROYCE:  They do this just for sport?
>
> NOLAND: Oh, yeah, ***they bring in fresh meat season after season. I mean, shit you wouldn't believe. Bring it in, and hunt it and kill it. In that order.***
>
> EDWIN: How long you been here, man?
>
> NOLAND: Uh... Seven seasons, I think. ...

The same is rephrased [*quite in detail*] in the first draft of the script as well:

> NOLAND: ***Every year they bring in the fresh meat. Shit you wouldn’t even believe. They hunt ‘em. Kill ‘em. But every so often one of us kills one of them. That’s when they get
> real interested. Slice the poor son of a bitch up. See what makes him tick. Next season, when they are back, maybe their weapons have changed, or maybe their armor. Maybe even them.***

Answer (score 4):

Based on the summary from the film's page on Wikipedia, the [Predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predators_(film)) themselves are responsible for abducting Royce and the others to the Game Preserve Planet.

This is outlined by Noland, who arrived some time earlier, when they encounter him

> The group encounters Ronald Noland, a solitary American soldier, who has survived on the planet for "ten seasons" by hiding and scavenging from the Predators and their victims. He explains that the **Predators hunt in threes and sharpen their killing skills by abducting warriors and dangerous beasts from other worlds** and bringing them to the planet.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, quoting the plot from Wikipedia (or other unsourced sites) doesn't always help.